# How to use ranging in didRangeBeaconsInRegion

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

**-------EDIT 2--------**

Still using the post of Davidgyoung and these comments, now I have a FatalException :

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   IntentService[BeaconIntentProcessor]
>       Process: databerries.beaconapp, PID: 19180
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at databerries.beaconapp.MyApplicationName.didEnterRegion(MyApplicationName.java:76)
>               at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor.onHandleIntent(BeaconIntentProcessor.java:83)
>               at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

This error is due to the calling of setRangeNotifier()?

**-------EDIT--------**

After the post of Davidgyoung and these comments, I tried this method, but still not working :

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private static final String TAG = ".MyApplicationName";
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

List region_list = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
    // wake up the app when any beacon is seen (you can specify specific id filers in the parameters below)
    List region_list = myRegionList();
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region_list);

    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3000l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000l);
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
    // Don't care
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
    // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
    // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.
    regionBootstrap.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
    // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);

    String zone = region.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "Enter in region");
    String text = "Enter in " + zone;
    Log.d(TAG, text);
    String uuid = "UUID : " + region.getId1();
    Log.d(TAG, uuid);
    //This part is not working
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);
    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
    // Don't care
}
```

The errors are about the input in `setRangeNotifier` and an exception for `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`

This isn't my main class, my main class :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myapp.MESSAGE";
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.d("myActivity","onCreate");

}
```

}

I want all the IDs of the beacons in the region. With this method if I understand, the app is wake-up in the background when she detected a region and normally the "startRangingBeaconsInRegion" can give me a list of beacons with this one I can take the Ids.

**-------Original--------**

I would like to know all the beacon around me. I know the UUID of this beacons and I can get it with 'region.toString();'. But, I need the others id of the beacons. And, I don't have "Beacon" on didRangeBeaconsInRegion.

How to know the beacons in the region?

And last question, it's possible to make that in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example of ranging for beacons in the "Ranging Sample Code" section here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

This will allow you to read all the identifiers by looking at each `Beacon` object returned in the `Collection<Beacon> beacons` in the callback.  Like this:

```
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
                Log.i(TAG, "This beacon has identifiers:"+beacon.getId1()+", "+beacon.getId2()+", "+beacon.getId3());        
            }
        }
```

Once you start ranging, it will continue to do so in the background, provided you don't exit the activity that starts the ranging.  Under some uses of the library, ranging slows down in the background, but this only happens if using the `BackgroundPowerSaver` class.  If you don't want ranging to slow down in the background, simply don't enable background power saving with the library.

Comment: Hum.. ok! But what is regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region) for? I don't need to implement BootstrapNotifier to use your service in the background?

Thanks for helping, I'm gonna try with your answer!

Comment: I don't succeed to use your code. Maybe is because I don't extend an Activity?
I just implements BeaconConsumer and give to the beaconManager the context of my mainActivity. @davidgyoung

Comment: And I need ranging when the application is killed.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to follow the examples.  If you want to automatically startup in the background and range, you are correct that you will need to use a `RegionBootstrap` class, which must be used from a custom `Application` class -- this is a valid but different approach than I described in this answer.  I would use the reference application as a starting point: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference  However, be realistic about what you can accomplish.  If a user kills the app, it will stop scanning until a reboot or power connect event.

Comment: I use this application as a starting point. But, I can't use an application class, I just can use the context. I succeed to using didEnterRegion for example.

But, now I need to run the ranging when I am in the didEnterRegion. And, I can't succeed this step.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to use an Application class for the `RegionBootstrap` to work.  Without it, the library won't be able to auto launch your app to scan for beacons.

Comment: ok, but can I use the ranging when I am in the didEnterRegion? how?

Comment: You can simply put the following code in the `didEnterRegion` callback:  `beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this); beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));`,

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have the time to test it this week end. I can't use these methods. I can't use the "This". I have to create a "new RangeNotifier()".
And when I create it I have a Fatal exception.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble following what you have tried and what exception you are getting.  Perhaps you can add this information to the bottom of your question under an **EDIT** section.

Comment: Edit Done @davidgyoung

Comment: In order to be able to call `setRangeNotifier(this)` on the `MyApplicationName` class, you need to make it implement `RangeNotifier` like this:  `public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, Range Notifier`.  You will also need to implement a `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method inside that class as described in my answer above.

Comment: Understand that calling `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` is what triggers the library to start sending callbacks to `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` with a list of all the beacons it discovered.

Comment: Yes I understand. But when I try this method I have a FATALEXCEPTION, I put it on a new edit.

Comment: Yes, I understand. And, why don't you give the beacons in the region when you call didEnterInRegion, like didEnterInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region), do you have any technical constraint ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75203/discussion-between-davidgyoung-and-david-cesar-santos).